# Is my question off topic? If not, how to get more attention?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I recently [asked this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/432404/46133) regarding simulation of Diffuse Interstellar Bands for molecules.

So far it had only 12 views and any interaction, is it off topic? If not, How do I get more attention?

Comment: Looks like most of your activity has been on Stack Overflow and Unix SE which are more active than Physics SE (i.e. their home pages completely refresh in a fifth of the time taken here), even though Physics is the 10th most active SE site (in terms of traffic), if I'm not mistaken. Give it some time, 12 views in 17 hours isn't extremely low here. There are no pending close votes; it looks on-topic and extremely interesting. I'm going to read some more about those stuff so I know what's happening when someone answers it :P

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! My background is in Informatics Engineering so I'm quite unfamiliar with this concepts/community

Comment: The question refers to a video which I doubt very many people will watch. Plus: the question is quite vague...

Comment: At least one of those visits was some guy editing your post too. Try not adding "Edit $n$" to your posts, just incorporate the new material naturally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So far it had only 12 views and any interaction

For a fairly-localized question on a technical topic, like yours, this isn't something that I would be alarmed about. Your question is on-topic (though maybe it falls on some pits that you could have avoided) and you're just seeing the normal pace of the site.

If your question doesn't get enough attention within a couple of days, you can set a bounty on it, which does tend to attract attention.

You can also post on meta and hope that the meta effect will bank you an answer, but that's *not* a general solution and intentional use of that phenomenon would be counted as abuse.